# How do I call a function in an AS2 swf hosted by an AS3 swf and return an array back to AS3 swf? (using SwfBridge)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, communication, localconnection

I have a Flash CS4 AS3 swf (host) that loads a Flash 8 AS2 swf (client) using gSkinner's swfBridge.

This works great and the Host can call functions in the client no problem. However I want to be able to call a function in the client and have that function return an array to the host.

This is the code I thought would work -

**Host (AS3) code -**

```
var hostArray:Array = new Array();
hostArray = mySwfBridge.send("getArray");
```

**Client (AS2) code**

```
var theArray = new Array("item1, item2, item3);
function getArray() :Array {
    return theArray;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem your exposed towards is that the `LocalConnection` (used by `SwfBridge`) does it calls asynchronously. In other words, the execution of the caller script won't halt its execution to await a result back from the invoked function.

If you need to retrieve a value from the other side of the `LocalConnection` you need to set it up to work bidirectionally. i.e. your client script must send its result back to a callback method on the host object via `LocalConnection` (`SwfBridge` in this case) instead of doing this via *`return`*.

Comment: Thanks Theo, by a callback method, do you mean that when the called function has completed I simply call a function in the original caller to handle what would have been sent by the return statement. I had thought of this but thought it was a bit untidy... if thats the only way though... many thanks :)